# Unable to access wordpress site non admin - 404 Not Found

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

I am able to access wp-admin part of my site but unable to access my wordpress site as plain..
That is I can do www.mysite.com/wp-admin and login,
But unable to view www.mysite.com/
Here is my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version wordpress you have use ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the theme. Just make sure that you assigned theme for your project. or download default theme and enable it and check.